# Unable to extend table "SYS.SYSAUTH$"

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am Using Oracle 12c and when tying to create a new workspace I am getting the following error :

```
ORA-20001: Error with: GRANT CREATE SESSION TO "MY_WORKSPACE_NAME" ORA-01653: unable to extend table SYS.SYSAUTH$ 
by 8 in tablespace SYSTEM
Error creating workspace.
```

Comment: Add some data files in SYSTEM tablespace or increase the size of the data file used in the SYSTEM tablespace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another data file in the `SYSTEM` tablespace or increase the `maxsize` of the data file(Auto extensible data file) of the SYSTEM tablespace.

```
-- Adding datafile in the tablespace
ALTER TABLESPACE <tablespace_name> ADD DATAFILE
    <datafile_path> SIZE <initial_size_of_DF>
        [AUTOEXTEND ON] NEXT <increment_size> MAXSIZE <max_allowed_size>
```

TO view the tablespace and datafile information, use following SQL:

```
SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME,
       FILE_NAME,
       USER_BYTES / 1024 / 1024 USED_SIZE_IN_MB,
       MAXBYTES / 1024 / 1024 MAX_SIZE_IN_MB,
       AUTOEXTENSIBLE
  FROM DBA_DATA_FILES
 WHERE TABLESPACE_NAME = 'SYSTEM';
```